# Cuda error of out_of_memory when running Tensor-Flow

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Tesla K80 to run Tensor-Flow and I am getting OUT_OF_MEMORY error. Can anyone help me how to resolve this problem?

---

Description:

1. NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU should have 11.87GB memory.
2. I've set the process to use 90% GPU memory.
3. I re-ran the program 3 times and each time it allowed me to run less steps until error occurred.

---

Logs:
1.

```
2017-03-28 23:34:34.252047: step 830, loss = 0.36 (124.4 examples/sec; 0.402 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:34:38.676589: step 840, loss = 0.41 (106.2 examples/sec; 0.471 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:34:42.826278: step 850, loss = 0.45 (116.0 examples/sec; 0.431 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:34:47.274519: step 860, loss = 0.41 (113.9 examples/sec; 0.439 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:34:51.793204: step 870, loss = 0.41 (129.7 examples/sec; 0.385 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:34:55.928524: step 880, loss = 0.40 (119.1 examples/sec; 0.420 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:35:00.152923: step 890, loss = 0.36 (129.1 examples/sec; 0.387 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:35:04.347550: step 900, loss = 0.35 (113.9 examples/sec; 0.439 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:35:11.431462: step 910, loss = 0.38 (109.9 examples/sec; 0.455 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:35:15.439966: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:35:15.440022: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
```

2.

```
Training from fresh start
2017-03-28 23:37:31.624590: step 0, loss = 0.73 (1.2 examples/sec; 41.462 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:37:40.920874: step 10, loss = 0.62 (116.7 examples/sec; 0.428 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:37:45.000310: step 20, loss = 0.55 (127.2 examples/sec; 0.393 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:37:49.345005: step 30, loss = 0.50 (109.1 examples/sec; 0.458 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:37:53.544604: step 40, loss = 0.46 (117.5 examples/sec; 0.426 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:37:57.696332: step 50, loss = 0.43 (122.8 examples/sec; 0.407 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:38:01.880436: step 60, loss = 0.44 (111.9 examples/sec; 0.447 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:38:06.169541: step 70, loss = 0.39 (97.2 examples/sec; 0.514 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:38:10.216505: step 80, loss = 0.41 (120.6 examples/sec; 0.414 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:38:14.399862: step 90, loss = 0.42 (119.3 examples/sec; 0.419 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:38:18.621185: step 100, loss = 0.42 (112.1 examples/sec; 0.446 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:38:19.485396: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:38:19.485583: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
2017-03-28 23:38:19.485729: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 7730940928 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:38:19.485823: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 7730940928
2017-03-28 23:38:19.485932: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 6957846528 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:38:19.486023: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 6957846528
2017-03-28 23:38:19.486165: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 6262061568 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:38:19.486233: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 6262061568
2017-03-28 23:38:19.486324: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 5635855360 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:38:19.486390: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 5635855360
Killed
```

3.

```
Training from fresh start
2017-03-28 23:39:55.459584: step 0, loss = 0.74 (1.2 examples/sec; 40.841 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:40:04.598183: step 10, loss = 0.63 (118.7 examples/sec; 0.421 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:40:08.637012: step 20, loss = 0.56 (128.6 examples/sec; 0.389 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:40:12.954617: step 30, loss = 0.52 (121.4 examples/sec; 0.412 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:40:17.101882: step 40, loss = 0.46 (133.6 examples/sec; 0.374 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:40:21.288942: step 50, loss = 0.44 (119.3 examples/sec; 0.419 sec/batch)
2017-03-28 23:40:24.083043: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:40:24.083350: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
2017-03-28 23:40:24.083532: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 7730940928 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:40:24.083630: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 7730940928
2017-03-28 23:40:24.083769: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 6957846528 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:40:24.083859: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 6957846528
2017-03-28 23:40:24.084943: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 6262061568 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:40:24.085062: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 6262061568
2017-03-28 23:40:24.086309: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 5635855360 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:40:24.086419: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 5635855360
2017-03-28 23:40:24.087551: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 5072269824 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-03-28 23:40:24.087658: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 5072269824
Killed
```

---

I know that GPU doesn't clean up the memory so that might be the reason that the available memory is getting less. But how can I resolve this? My program is training a deep-learning model and I don't think I can clean up the memory during training.

PS: I am not sure if I should set the program to use at most some fraction of memory or set the program to `allow_growth == True`.

Comment: you are actually reading the error messages? It is your CPU that is running out of physical memory, not your GPU.

Comment: It is cuda error right? So it is GPU running out of memory? Or you are saying the host means cpu?

Comment: Host means CPU. The error comes from a CUDA API which allocates physical CPU memory and pins it so that the GPU can use it for DMA transfers to and from the GPU and CPU. You are running out of CPU memory

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this. Could you also help me calculate the CPU memory I need? Does it depend on my training data or num of GPUs?

Comment: How are you feeding data to the model? Memory usage often gets out of control if training data is embedded in the graph (e.g. with a `tf.constant`), in which case switching over to a `feed_dict` or queue-based input would keep memory usage constant across steps.

Comment: Have you found a solution since you posted this question?